# Conditionally select rows of matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am looking for a more efficient way to get a simple task done in MATLAB. My code works but seems overly verbose for what I want to accomplish. I have a matrix of years with corresponding values, where years can be repeated. For example:

```
...

1910 1.04

1910 2.53

1910 0.94

1911 2.13

1911 5.32

...
```

I want to pick a range of years and take the average over all values in the second column which have their year in that range. The way I am currently doing this is

```
years = rawdata(:,yearcolumn);             %extracts year vector from data
rows_to_keep = years>=firstyear_i&years<maxyear;  %rows we are considering
levels = [years,rawdata(:,datacolumn)];    %new vector where first column shows if being considered and second is rawdata for that row
indices1 = find(levels(:,1)==0);           %indexes rows for deletion
indices2 = find(levels(:,1)==1);           %indexes rows we are using
levels(indices2,1) = rawdata(indices2,1);  %if using row, replace "1" with appropriate year from rawdata
levels(indices1,:) = [];                   %if not using row, remove it from data we are considering
```

I am wondering if there is a better way to do either this. Thanks!

Edit: for anyone looking at this horrible code that I wrote, DO NOT do anything I did. See the selected answer for a description on logical indexing, which is the correct way to do any type of data selection like this in MATLAB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few too many steps in there.  Just use an index of what you want and take the average.  Like this:

```
values = [1910 1.04;1910 2.53;1910 0.94;1911 2.13;1911 5.32];
index = values(:,1) == 1910;
av = mean(values(index, 2));
```

For this case `av = 1.503333333333`.

To save out just the stuff (and not remove everything later) do this.

```
stuffToKeep = values(index,:);
stuffToKeep = values(values(:,1) == 1910,:); % 1-liner if you don't want to save the index
```

If you want to retain information for later, just save the index and recall it when you need it.

```
years = unique(values(:,1));
% then find all the values that match each year
[~, yearIndex] = ismember(values(:,1), years);
% use the index
mean(values(yearIndex == 1,2)); % same as before average of 1910
mean(values(yearIndex == 2,2)); % average of 1911
```

What to a range?  Same logic.

```
index = values(:,1) >= 1910 & values(:,1) <= 1920;
mean(values(index,2)); %average of values between 1910 and 1920 inclusive.
```

Here is a good [example](https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html) of indexing from Mathworks people.  Also try typing `logical indexing` into the help.

Comment: This is exactly what I was overlooking. I forgot that logical indexing works this way in MATLAB :). I knew I had way too many steps, hence why I came here haha.